# joomla Access level not working in k2 backend

Tags: joomla2.5, backend, user-permissions, joomla-k2

(all of my problems is in joomla administrator interface (back end))
for sample. in joomla access level viwing i create an access leve & set just super admin user group can be access to this level.
in back end: in joomla content when i create an article with this access level, whene other user group login to backend, they cant see the articles with this access & just super admin can see this article in backend.
but in k2 this option not working:
when i create item with super user access leve in back end:
whene other user group login to backend, they can see this item in backend.
this is a big problem .
please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to read and understand your problem specifically.

I guess that your problem is that you don't know how to set the Joomla ACL correctly, so that's why you face these problems.

I suggest you read [this article](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-may-2012/item/761-Joomla-ACL-Configuring-back-end) to help understand the concept of Joomla ACL.
Alternatively, I suggest you watch the author's videos on [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com) video tutorials, they are very good.

Comment: Oops, i just saw that this question is one year old. I thought it was just some days old.. Jeez..